# Restore edittext value while navigating activity

Tags: android, null, android-edittext, retain

I have a simple edittext on first activity and user enter some text and moves to second activity and from there to third and so on.
Now when the user comes back to first activity the edit text should show him the text he enetered in the edittext.

```
SampleText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.smpltxt);
SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
```

Saving the value :

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

  savedInstanceState.putString("MyString", SampleText);
}
```

Restoring the value :

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

  String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("MyString");
}
```

I'm unable to get the text when he comes back to the first activity.

Can anyone say me what and where am I going wrong ?

Comment: You should try application class, although it may be troublesome in some conditions.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple after a lot of hair pulling.

Added in `onBackPressed()` event of Activity2:

```
 public void onBackPressed() {
  finish();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
savedInstanceState.putString("MyString", SampleText);
```

with

```
savedInstanceState.putString("MyString", SampleText.getText().toString());
```

also check whether `SampleText.getText()==null` if so no need to add it.

Comment: @Apoorv-thanks for your answer..butit didn't work out as when I'm moving from Activity A to B and coming back to Activity A there is nothing in edittext and it's showing blank.

Comment: What did you get in `myString`?

Comment: @VinodKumar- Updated with my answer at top. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I think the default behavior makes sure text in `EditText`s is saved.
Anyway: this is how to do it:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContent(/* your layout */);
  SampleText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.smpltxt);

  if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("MyString");
    SampleText.setText(myString);
  }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  savedInstanceState.putString("MyString", SampleText.getText().toString());
}
```